Batch file to output & rename file, delete original file, rename output to original filename
I have a batch file to recursively process .mp4 files with ffmpeg. This renames the original file basename with _2 suffixed. It then deletes the original file before renaming output file to the original filename. (I currently use a PowerShell script for this final step).
FOR /r %%I in (*.mp4) DO (
    ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -metadata:s:v:0 language=eng -c:v copy -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -c:a copy "%%~pnI_2.mp4"
    del /Q /S "%%I" 
)

Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  "H:\Downloads\! Convert Video\rename.ps1"

The script has proven unreliable when recursing into folders within the parent folder. I wonder if anyone has a suggestion or a suitable batch file solution for this task?
I have tried many different things, but all of them have failed in one way or another. I usually end up without renaming the output file.

I would start by changing your for loop to For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "*.mp4" /A:-D /B 2^>NUL') Do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%G" -metadata:s:v:0 language=eng -c:v copy -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -c:a copy "%%~dpnG_2%%~xG" && Del "%%I" /A /F. You could probably replace the PowerShell command and file with another for loop too.

Why not rename the file after the del command?

Apologies, I somehow omitted the recursive /S option with the Dir command I posted in my opening conment, (as later noted by @Mofi; thanks).

@Compo I have tried running the batch with a second for loop, but the second for loop does not appear to run at all, I'm not sure why though?
Your script succeeds, but the files are not renamed and I can't get a second for loop to run for some reason?

I suggest using this batch file for the task.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Does ffmpeg.exe exist in the current working directory?
if exist ffmpeg.exe for %%I in (ffmpeg.exe) do set "FFMPEGEXE=%%~fI" & goto ProcessFiles
rem Search for ffmpeg.exe in folders of environment variable PATH.
rem There is executed set "FFMPEGEXE=" if the executable file can't be found.
for %%I in (ffmpeg.exe) do set "FFMPEGEXE=%%~$PATH:I"
rem Does ffmpeg.exe exist in any folder of environment variable PATH?
if defined FFMPEGEXE goto ProcessFiles
echo ERROR: Could not find ffmpeg.exe!
echo(
pause
exit /B 1

rem The required executable is present and its fully qualified file name
rem is assigned to the environment variable FFMPEGEXE. The Windows Command
rem Processor must not search once again for this executable file on using
rem the full file name of the executable in the next command lines.

:ProcessFiles
rem Remove all read-only attributes from all MP4 files.
%SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -R /S *.mp4 1>nul

rem Process all MP4 files in the current working directory and all
rem its subdirectories with archive attribute set. The archive
rem attribute is removed from each successfully processed file.
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "*.mp4" /AA-D-L /B /S 2^>nul') do "%FFMPEGEXE%" -f mp4 -i "%%I" -metadata:s:v:0 language=eng -c:v copy -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -c:a copy "%%~dpnI.tmp" && move /Y "%%~dpnI.tmp" "%%I" 1>nul && %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -A "%%I"

endlocal

The FOR loop could be written also using a command block:
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "*.mp4" /AA-D-L /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    echo Processing "%%I"...
    "%FFMPEGEXE%" -f mp4 -i "%%I" -metadata:s:v:0 language=eng -c:v copy -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -c:a copy "%%~dpnI.tmp"
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        move /Y "%%~dpnI.tmp" "%%I" 1>nul
        if not errorlevel 1 %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -A "%%I"
    )
    del "%%~dpnI.tmp" 2>nul
)

The batch file could process hundreds or even thousands of video files. The usage of just ffmpeg or ffmpeg.exe without full path would require a search for this file by cmd.exe in file system as described by this answer on each MP4 file to process. That would cause hundreds or even thousands of file system accesses just for searching again and again for this executable file. It is therefore better doing the search once at the beginning and get the fully qualified file name (drive + path + name + extension) of ffmpeg.exe. Then this executable is referenced with its full name in the FOR loop which avoids any additional file system access just for finding this executable.
There is executed first the command ATTRIB for removal of the read-only attribute on any MP4 file in the current working directory and all its subdirectories. That is important because of the command move used later would prompt the user for confirmation replacing the existing destination file with read-only attribute set despite the usage of option /Y. The prompt cannot be seen by the user of the batch script because of using 1>nul to prevent the output of 1 file(s) moved. into the console window.
The usage of a for /F loop is very important here as otherwise it could happen that some MP4 files are skipped and some are processed multiple times and in worst case the FOR loop results in an endless running loop depending on file system (NTFS and ReFS versus FAT32 and exFAT). For more details see: At which point does for or for /R enumerate the directory (tree)?
There is executed in background %ComSpec% /c with the command line as specified within '. There is run for that reason in background:
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c dir "*.mp4" /AA-D-L /B /S 2>nul

The command DIR searches

in the current directory and all its subdirectories because of option /S
just for files with archive attribute because of option /AA-D-L (attribute archive and not directory attribute and not link attribute)
of which long or short file name is matched by the wildcard pattern *.mp4
and outputs just the file name because of option /B (bare format)
with full path because of option /S without surrounding ".

It is possible that DIR finds no matching file system entry and outputs therefore an error message to handle STDERR of the background command process which would be seen in the console window. The usage of 2>nul suppresses this error message.
Read the Microsoft documentation about Using command redirection operators for an explanation of 2>nul. The redirection operator > must be escaped with caret character ^ on FOR command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command FOR which executes the embedded dir command line with using a separate command process started in background.
Every matching file name with full path not enclosed in " output by DIR to handle STDOUT of background command process is captured by cmd.exe processing the batch file to its process memory.
Once DIR finished and background started cmd.exe closed itself, FOR processes the list of file names in memory of cmd.exe which is processing the batch file. Changes in the file table of the file system on *.mp4 files do not change anymore the list of file names to process.
FOR /F splits up by default each non-empty line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and assigns just the first space/tab separated substring to the specified loop variable I if not beginning with the default end of line character ; (semicolon) after the removal of leading spaces/tabs too. The full file names output by DIR can contain one or more spaces. The unwanted line splitting behavior is disabled here by using delims= which defines an empty list of string delimiters. DIR outputs each file name with full path and therefore no line begins ever with a semicolon. The default end of line character definition does not matter in this case.
There is executed for each MP4 file with an archive attribute now ffmpeg.exe with its full path. The fully qualified MP4 file name is passed as input file name after option -i to ffmpeg. The output file name is nearly the same. There is just the file extension changed to .tmp. That makes it possible to break the batch file processing at any time resulting in leaving behind in worst case just one .tmp file of the currently processed video file. The option -f mp4 must be used in this case to inform ffmpeg about the output format because it cannot guess it anymore from the file extension of the output file. The ffmpeg documentation explains the option -f in section Main options and also the other used options.
The program ffmpeg exits with 0 on success and with a value greater 0 on an error. This information is used with the conditional command operator && or with if not errorlevel 1 to run the next command only if processing of the current MP4 file finished successfully.
The command MOVE is used with option /Y to delete in file table of the file system the file name of the currently processed MP4 file and then change the file name of the temporary output file to name of the MP4 file in file table of the file system. There are no data copied or moved by this command. The information about successful deletion and rename of temporary file to input file is suppressed by redirecting it to device NUL.
The command MOVE sets the dynamic variable ERRORLEVEL of the Windows Command Processor to 0 on success and to 1 on an error occurred. The command ATTRIB is executed on success to remove the archive attribute from the completely processed MP4 file.
The single line solution keeps the *.tmp file while the multi-line solution deletes the *.tmp file on anything went wrong.
There should be considered that the processing of all MP4 files could be stopped for whatever reason like user pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break and confirming the termination of the batch file execution, or the user clicks on X symbol of the console window, or Windows must be shut down immediately, or a driver causes a blue screen condition.
That is the reason why the archive attribute is removed from each MP4 file processed successfully and why the FOR loop processes only MP4 files with archive attribute set on searching for file names matching the wildcard pattern. The not successfully processed MP4 files with their .tmp files perhaps still existing are processed once again on running the batch file later once again on same directory tree while the successfully processed video files are ignored on every further execution of the batch file on same directory tree. The temporary files are overwritten on second run as long as the video files with same file name and file extension .mp4 still exist.
There could be added a command line like del /A /F /Q /S *.tmp 2>nul for the deletion of every file with file extension .tmp before endlocal. But that is only useful if cmd.exe can really execute this command line which is not the case in the scenarios described above.
This method makes it also possible copying new video files into the directory tree or modifying existing video files in the directory tree on which Windows sets automatically the archive attribute and then run the batch file once again to process only the new/modified video files.
To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

attrib /?
del /?
dir /?
echo /?
endlocal /?
exit /?
for /?
goto /?
move /?
pause /?
rem /?
set /?
setlocal /?

See also:

How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?
What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?
DosTips forum topic: ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/
Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file for an explanation of the conditional command operator &&.

